# complexity of -Count the number of identical trees in a given Tree

Tags: algorithm, recursion, tree, binary-tree, time-complexity

Count the number of identical trees in a given Tree, where a tree is said to be identical if the values of its node is same as its the value of all its children nodes, We can make the assumption that the tree is a binary tree

For each node  I need to check if its is an identical tree
hence for every node I traverse the tree below it, i e the node and its tree to see if they are identical .

since I do a post order traversal to count tree, 
Im not sure how to calculate the time complexity

Comment: Time complexity will be O (N) because you will have to traverse the tree in post order. So will be space complexity because you will need an external stack for the parent nodes.

Comment: We need some precision here : "a tree is said to be identical if the values of its node is same as its the value of all its children nodes". Should it be "a tree is said to be identical if the values of its node is same as its the SUM OF the value of all its children nodes" ? More generally, what is "the value [singular] of all its children nodes [plural]" ?